# Getting 404 errors when trying to use Fontawesome fonts locally in express.js framework

Tags: node.js, font-awesome

When I try to use fontawesome locally I am always getting 404 error when the browser tries to load the fonts. I'm pretty sure I have set the path correctly.

I have set the static paths in app.js as follows.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Content'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/webfonts'));
```

[image: 404 errors]

Comment: And what are the questions marks in the expolorer? Are the files present on the file system when you go there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing webfonts at the `/webfonts` endpoint, but when you do not provide a path as the first parameter, it will be hosted at root. So, either reference the webfonts without the `/webfonts` prefix, or try giving them an endpoint as the first parameter:

```
app.use('/Content', express.static(__dirname + '/Content'));
app.use('/webfonts', express.static(__dirname + '/webfonts'));
```

See [Express Docs - app.use](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use)